# Format text in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

How to Write a parser/method in javascript which would parse the below text?

#### Input

```
  digraph "com.a:test:jar:1.0" { 
     "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> 
     "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile"; 
     "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.2:compile"; 
     "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "info.picocli:picocli:jar:2.3.0:compile"; 
     "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile"; 
     "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:jar:3.21.0:compile";
     "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile" -> 
     "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.9:compile" ; 
     "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile" -> "commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile" ; 
     "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile" -> "commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile" ; 
      }
```

#### Desired Output

```
 digraph "com.a:test:jar:1.0" { 
         "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> 
         "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile"; 
         "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.2:compile"; 
         "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "info.picocli:picocli:jar:2.3.0:compile"; 
         "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile"; 
         "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:jar:3.21.0:compile";
          }
```

i.e anything appearing next to diagraph "com.a:test:jar:1.0", if it appears before (LHS) `->` have it else omit it.

Note: there can be multiple blocks of digraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to do part of the parsing, and use the `replace` callback to keep/eliminate the relevant parts:

```js
function clean(input) {
    let keep;
    return input.replace(/^\s*digraph\s+("[^"]*")\s*\{|\s*("[^"]+")\s*->\s*"[^"]+"\s*;|([^])/gm, 
        (m, a, b, c) => a && (keep = a) || b === keep || c ? m : ""
    );
}

// Example:
var input = `digraph "com.a:test:jar:1.0" { 
     "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> 
     "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile"; 
     "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.2:compile"; 
     "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "info.picocli:picocli:jar:2.3.0:compile"; 
     "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile"; 
     "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:jar:3.21.0:compile";
     "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile" -> 
     "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.9:compile" ; 
     "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile" -> "commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile" ; 
     "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile" -> "commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile" ; 
      }`

console.log(clean(input));
```